# LibGDX - Gwt - Sounds Don't Play On Mobile Browsers

Tags: audio, gwt, browser, libgdx, mp3

I developed a game in LibGDX.
I added some sound effects in mp3 format into my project.
When I deploy my project to HTML, browsers on PC play those sounds, but browsers on mobile phones don't play them.
How can I solve this problem?